# Reshaping string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a coding question where I need to create function to reshape/regroup a string and separate the next group by newline.

The function `reshape` will accept 2 parameters, the length of the group and the string to reshape. It'll disregard space in the string, i.e.

```
reshape(1,"AB CD") #returns A\nB\nC\nD
reshape(6, "AB CD SDSD SDSDSDSDSDSD") #returns ABCDSD\nSDSDSD\nSDSDSD\nSD
```

This is the my current code

```
def reshape(n, str):
    # remove space
    str = ''.join(str.split())
    lines = []
    buff = ''
    for ind,s in enumerate(str):
        # keep adding the buffer
        if len(buff) < n:
            buff += s
        else:
            # if the buffer length exceeds the max group length, add to the return list
            lines.append(buff)
            # reset the buffer
            buff = s

    return '\\n'.join(lines)
```

In my function, the answer somehow always miss the last group part. Is there something wrong with the logic?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved more efficiently with iterators. Also, don't call your variables `str`, it overwrites the built-in `str`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def reshape(n, string):
    # remove space
    string = string.replace(' ', '')
    lines = (''.join(chars) for chars in zip_longest(*([iter(string)] * n), fillvalue=''))

    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

Output:

```
reshape(1,"AB CD")
'A\nB\nC\nD'

reshape(6, "AB CD SDSD SDSDSDSDSDSD")
'ABCDSD\nSDSDSD\nSDSDSD\nSD'
```

BTW, it's about 4-5x faster than the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you did not enter the last buffer item to the list in case it doesn't exceed the max group length.

Try adding this after the loop:

```
if(buff):
    lines.append(buff)
```